# Using threading to plot data of a different class in the background of a command line interface (CLI)

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line-interface

I am trying to plot a variable battery voltage on the background while the command line code keeps running as the program is executed. 
The plot begins when the user press plot and ends when exit is pressed.

```
from threading import Thread
import cmd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from drawnow import *

plt.ion() 
count=0


class myThreadPlot (Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.state = test()
        self.battVoltagePlot= []
        self.flag = True

    def run(self): 
        global  count     
        while self.flag:
            self.battVoltagePlot.append(self.state.batteryVoltage)                     
            drawnow(self.plot_var,stop_on_close=True)
            count+=1
            if count>50: self.battVoltagePlot.pop(0) # to plot 50 values at 
            a time

            plt.pause(1e-4)
        plt.close() 



    def plot_var(self):
        x =min(self.battVoltagePlot)
        y = max(self.battVoltagePlot)
        if x<0: plt.ylim(2*x,2*y)
        else: plt.ylim(x/2,2*y)                               
        plt.grid(True)                                  
        plt.ylabel('V')
        plt.plot(self.battVoltagePlot, 'ro-', label='V')        



class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.batteryVoltage =30



class CLI(cmd.Cmd):   
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)  
        self.prompt = ">> "
        self.intro  = ("Welcome\n Press help to see the options.\n  press 
        plot to plot battery voltage and press exit to exit ")


    def do_plot(self,arg): 
        "calling myThreadPLot to plot a variable 'batteryVoltage' from  
        class 'test' in the background"
        self.my = myThreadPlot()
        self.my.start()


    def do_exit(self, arg):  
        '''Exit this application'''
        print("Bye")
        self.my.flag = False
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
     CLI().cmdloop()
```

I am getting the following error as i press exit.

```
Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('main thread is not in main loop',) in 
<bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <Tkinter.PhotoImage instance at 
0x7f38f5412320>> ignored
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

Any suggestion on how can i use prevent this. Another issue is that 
in the drawnow(self.plot_var,stop_on_close=True) i am allowing the user to close the figure by clicking the cancel button. but when i tried it again errors pops up.

Comment: Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
func(*targs, **kargs)
File "/home/arauf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py", line 78, in destroy_allmanager.destroy()
File "/home/arauf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 557, in destroy
self.canvas._tkcanvas.after_cancel(self.canvas._idle_callback)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 612, in after_cance

Comment: Can you put that error in a code block in the question itself. Much more readable that way.

Comment: I have transferred your error message to the main text, where you can format it. It seems that part of it is missing. Please add the relevant information.

Comment: its done . I've added some more explanation as well